# How to introduce your own style when using Snipcart?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, snipcart

I'm building an ecommerce platform using GatsbyJS and Snipcart. It works well, but I want to override the default theme provided by Snipcart, and when I want to change the main default CSS through `gatsby-config.js` for some reason, it does not work.
Anyone has a solution? Thanks.
This code below makes the snipcart to stop functioning, exactly when I add the styles option:

```
  {
    resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-snipcartv3',
    options: {
      apiKey: 'API_IS_HIDDEN_FOR_A_REASON',
      autopop: true,
      styles: '.src/components/layout.css'
    }
  },
```

The question is how to make Snipcart version 3 to accept different styles provided by me when used with `GatsbyJS`? I tried their documentation, but there was not much, also looked on `github` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to do this was as follows:

1. In the snipcart plugin config options, set styles to false so it doesn't link the default stylesheet

```js
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-snipcartv3',
  options: {
    apiKey: process.env.SNIPCART_KEY,
    autopop: false,
    styles: false
    }
 }
```

2. Create a new stylesheet (e.g., src/styles/cart.css)
3. Copy the styles from Snipcart's default stylesheet into your cart.css, and make your desired customizations
4. Import your cart.css into your Layout component (or into gatsby-browser.js)